# Splash Screen Doesn't Display First On The Application

Tags: android, android-intent, android-studio, splash-screen

Good day, I'm doing a project and, I'm new with android development also, I just want to ask how to display my[the] splash screen first on my app (when starting up my application). Whenever I run it on emulator or on my device it directly go to my main activity.

Splash Screen Image

[image]

Main NavDrawer

[image]

I even reorder my manifest file list - and place the splash screen first
here my code

```
<!-- For Splash Screen -->
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.SplashScreen"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>



    <!-- For Main Activity -->
    <activity android:name=".activities.MainActivity" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Whenever I exit my app and start again, my splash screen is gone! It directly go to Main Activity.

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are having **2** LAUCHERS...

Make sure that only the Splash Screen Activity is the LAUNCHER.
Let the Main Activity be a DEFAULT one (and also the HOME one).

Comment: How about the rest of my activity should I put DEFAULT on it?

Comment: So I just leave it? Blank? 

Whenever I exit my app and start again, my splash screen is gone! It directly go to Main Activity. I already changed my Main to DEFAULT.